# Как в маршрутизации symfony сделать универсальный маршут?

Tags: php, symfony, маршрутизация

Есть множество контроллеров, у которых принцип работы одинаковый. Располагаются они все по namespace `app\presentation\controllers`. Именование у всех стандартное с постфиксом `Controller`. Все методы, которые вызываются по запросу тоже стандартные и имеют префикс `action`. Подскажите, как можно реализовать универсальный маршрут по такому шаблону: `/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/` или `/{controller}/{action}/`.

Была попытка такой реализации, но не удается автоматически передавать параметры:

```php
$routes->add('default', new Route('/{controller}/{action}', [
    '_controller' => static function (Request $request) {
        $controller = $request->attributes->get('controller');
        $action = $request->attributes->get('action');
        $controllerClassName =
            'app\\presentation\\controllers\\'
            . implode('', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-',$controller)))
            . 'Controller';
        $controllerClass = new $controllerClassName;
        
        return call_user_func_array([$controllerClass, $action], $request->query->all());
    }
]));
```

Само приложение выглядит так:

```php
class App {
    private UrlMatcher $matcher;
    private ControllerResolver $controllerResolver;
    private ArgumentResolver $argumentResolver;
    
    public function __construct(UrlMatcher $matcher, ControllerResolver $controllerResolver, ArgumentResolver $argumentResolver)
    {
        $this->matcher = $matcher;
        $this->controllerResolver = $controllerResolver;
        $this->argumentResolver = $argumentResolver;
    }
    
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        $this->matcher->getContext()->fromRequest($request);
        
        try {
            $request->attributes->add($this->matcher->match($request->getPathInfo()));
            
            $controller = $this->controllerResolver->getController($request);
            $arguments = $this->argumentResolver->getArguments($request, $controller);
            
            $response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);
            $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/json');
            
            return $response;
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $exception) {
            return new Response('Not Found', 404);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return new Response('An error occurred', 500);
        }
    }
}
```

И корневой файл, который все это дело запускает:

```php
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$routes = include __DIR__ . '/config/routes.php';

$context = new RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($request);
$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);
$controllerResolver = new ControllerResolver();
$argumentResolver = new ArgumentResolver();

$framework = new App($matcher, $controllerResolver, $argumentResolver);
$response = $framework->handle($request);

$response->send();
```

**UPD**.

Если добавить такой метод получения параметров, но это будет актуально только для `$_GET` запросов, но есть проблема с отловом ошибок:

```php
$arguments = $request->query->all();

array_shift($arguments);

return call_user_func_array([$controllerClass, $action], $arguments);
```

Выдает на экран при включенном дебаге:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function app\presentation\controllers\LeapYearController::index(), 0 passed in /var/www/php/custom-framework/config/routes.php on line 29 and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/php/custom-framework/app/presentation/controllers/LeapYearController.php:12
>
> Stack trace: #0 /var/www/php/custom-framework/config/routes.php(29): app\presentation\controllers\LeapYearController->index()
>
> #1 [internal function]: {closure}()
>
> #2 /var/www/php/custom-framework/app/App.php(34): call_user_func_array()
>
> #3 /var/www/php/custom-framework/index.php(28): app\App->handle()
>
> #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/php/custom-framework/app/presentation/controllers/LeapYearController.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

Вам явно нужно ознакомиться с [документацией](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) Symfony по ее роутингу.

Пример из документации:

```
// src/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog", name="blog_list")
     */
    public function list()
    {
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/blog/{item}", name="blog_item")
     */
    public function list(string $item)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Комментарий над методом, в Symfony отвечает за роутинг, это один из вариантов реализации, но нынче, самый популярный (аннотации).

Вы так же можете указать такой же блок для всего класса, если просто его скопируете. Это нужно для построения подобных роутов: `/api/v1/` (роут класса к примеру) + `blog` = `/api/v1/blog` и `/api/v1/blog/{item}` соответственно.

UPD: типизация для параметра необязательна, но если вы хотите, то никто вам это не запрещает, даже если в действительности там будет строка, а в укажете `int`, динамическая типизация касатнет ее в `int`.